# Responsive Navigation in HTML/CSS using Foundation framework

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am trying to replicate the following codepen navigation bar although I have a simple logo on the left and two links on the right. The framework used is Zurb Foundation: https://codepen.io/IamManchanda/pen/LymroM?editors=1000

So far I cannot seem to get the menu responsive. When I use a large window, the mobile menu stays put and will not toggle like in the pen. Any ideas how to replicate this?

Template:

```
<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="navbar" data-hide-for="medium">
   <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle="navbar"></button>
   <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
</div>

<div class="top-bar" id="navbar">
  <div class="top-bar-left">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menu-text">
        <a href="http://www.hanyu.co/default.aspx"><img id="logo" src="./assets/img/logo4white.png" alt="logo">HANYU.CO</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="top-bar-right">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li id="home"><router-link class="link align-left" to="/">Home</router-link></li>
      <li id="logout" v-if="this.$cookies.get('user')" @click="logout"><a>Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was not calling `$(document).foundation();` in the JavaScript. Oops!